# RaptureXML Problems parsing a certain rss feed

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, xml-parsing, string-parsing

I'm trying to parse a certain rss feed of a popular german news site ([taz.de](http://www.taz.de/!p3270;rss/)). Unfortunately, their description tag doesn't only contain plain text but a mixture of anything, including pictures, links etc.

```
<description>
    <![CDATA[<a href="http://www.taz.de/10-Jahre-nach-dem-Irakkrieg/!113046/"><img align="left" style="margin-right:5px;" src="/uploads/images/152x76/18032013_Bush_Irakkrieg_rtr.jpg" border="0" width="152" height="76" /></a>Das Land ist von einem funktionierenden Rechtsstaat weit entfernt. Zehn Jahre nach dem Irakkrieg zeigt sich eine niederschmetternde Bilanz. <a href="http://www.taz.de/10-Jahre-nach-dem-Irakkrieg/!113046/">mehr...</a>]]>
</description>
```

The only thing I'm interested in is the text `Das Land ist von einem funktionierenden Rechtsstaat weit entfernt. Zehn Jahre nach dem Irakkrieg zeigt sich eine niederschmetternde Bilanz.` How would I do that in an efficient way (without terrible string operations)? Since there is no attribute name, I guess I'm screwed? I'm using RaptureXML but if there's a better library for this problem, I'd switch the xml parser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's worse than that: The "CDATA" section means that the description (modulo surrounding whitespace) is the **literal string**

```
<a href="http://www.taz.de/10-Jahre-nach-dem-Irakkrieg/!113046/"><img align="left" style="margin-right:5px;" src="/uploads/images/152x76/18032013_Bush_Irakkrieg_rtr.jpg" border="0" width="152" height="76" /></a>Das Land ist von einem funktionierenden Rechtsstaat weit entfernt. Zehn Jahre nach dem Irakkrieg zeigt sich eine niederschmetternde Bilanz. <a href="http://www.taz.de/10-Jahre-nach-dem-Irakkrieg/!113046/">mehr...</a>
```

i.e. your snippet is equivalent to

```
<description>
    &lt;a href="http://www.taz.de/10-Jahre-nach-dem-Irakkrieg/!113046/"&gt;&lt;img align="left" style="margin-right:5px;" src="/uploads/images/152x76/18032013_Bush_Irakkrieg_rtr.jpg" border="0" width="152" height="76" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;Das Land ist von einem funktionierenden Rechtsstaat weit entfernt. Zehn Jahre nach dem Irakkrieg zeigt sich eine niederschmetternde Bilanz. &lt;a href="http://www.taz.de/10-Jahre-nach-dem-Irakkrieg/!113046/"&gt;mehr...&lt;/a&gt;
</description>
```

A conforming XML parser **cannot** give you the text you're looking for. You have two options:

- Wrap the string in e.g. `<foo>...</foo>`, pass *that* through the XML parser, and pull out all the text children of the root element.
- Wrap the string in something like `<html><title></title><body>...</body></html>`, pass it through an HTML parser (or any tag-soup-du-jour parser), and pull out all the text children of the body element.

I wonder if taz.de breaks if the description contains `]]>`...